# Protege ontologies (OWL) : When to use object properties and when to use data properties

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm having difficulties understanding when to use object properties and when to use data properties. I've read the definitions, but yet I'm having issues using them in a practical setting.

It would be of much help if anyone could correct the following example.

Let's say I'm making a Wine ontology, with some subclasses redWine, whiteWin, sparklingWine and so on. How will I then manage the properties for example goesWithFoodType, fromCountry and hasGrapeType? All in which have subproperties down the hierachy. Will all of these be data properties with the domain Wine and ranges xsd:string datatype?

If the things stated above is correct, would I have any use from object properties in my ontology?

Thanks.

Comment: You should learn about the difference between individuals and literals in OWL. Obviously, you could not add any statements about the food type, country, etc. if those are just literal values of type `xsd:string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I recognize object properties vs datatype properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724983/how-can-i-recognize-object-properties-vs-datatype-properties)