# How do I add a type/interface for nested objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this object that I need to send to a component.

```
{
    key: "1",
    label: "Folder 7",
    icon: "fa fa-folder",
    title: "Desktop Folder",
    children: [
      {
        key: "1-0",
        label: "Folder 8",
        icon: "fa fa-folder",
        title: "Documents Folder",
      },
      {
        key: "1-1",
        label: "Folder 9",
        icon: "fa fa-folder",
        title: "Documents Folder",
      },
    ],
  }
```

I wrote this interface for it :

```
interface Node {
    node: {
        key: string
        label: string
        icon: string
        title: string
        children: Array<Node>
    }
}
```

but this gives an error

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ key: string; label: string; icon: string; title: string; children: Node[]; }': key, label, icon, title, children

The component where I'm passing the prop from :

```
interface TreeProps{
    data: Array<object>
}

const Tree: FC<TreeProps> = ({data=[]}) => {
    return (
        <div>
             <div className="d-tree">
                 <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
                     {data.map(tree => (
                         <TreeNode node={tree}/>
                     ))}
                 </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The component where I'm taking in the prop:

```
type Node  = {
    node: {
        key: string
        label: string
        icon: string
        title: string
        children: Node[]
    }
}

const TreeNode: FC<Node> = ({node}) => {

    const [childVisiblity, setChildVisibility] = useState(false);

    const hasChild = node.children ? true : false;

    return (
        <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
            <div className="d-flex" onClick={e => setChildVisibility(!childVisiblity)}>
                {hasChild && (
                <div className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${childVisiblity ? "active" : "" }`}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretRight}/>
                </div>
                )}

                <div className="col d-tree-head">
                    <i className={`mr-1 ${node.icon}`}></i>
                    {node.label}
                </div>
            </div>
            

            {
                hasChild && childVisiblity && <div className="d-tree-content">
                    <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
                        <Tree data={node.children}/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
        </li>
    )
}
```

Do I need to tell the component that the array has objects? How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a `node` property inside the `Node` interface but your data does not have a `node` property?

Comment: ``` const TreeNode: FC<Node> = ({node}) => { } ```
Needed it below like this also each child is also of the type node but how to I assign the type of those props as an object without using a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the interface to for example **INode** (I- interface)

Also, add `?` to the children property in the interface to fix recursion.

```
interface INode {
      key: string
      label: string
      icon: string
      title: string
      children?: INode[]
}


const data: INode = {
  key: "1",
  label: "Folder 7",
  icon: "fa fa-folder",
  title: "Desktop Folder",
  children: [
    {
      key: "1-0",
      label: "Folder 8",
      icon: "fa fa-folder",
      title: "Documents Folder",
    },
    {
      key: "1-1",
      label: "Folder 9",
      icon: "fa fa-folder",
      title: "Documents Folder",
    },
  ],
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-poincare-0lf6c

The problem is with **Node** name, because the name is reserved in TS.

Comment: Questioner wanted the root interface to have property `node`... i think?

Comment: Can't have it optional as I'm using node.children below. That would give an error.

Comment: So just remove `?`.  I thought this should be inserted to eliminate errors. Because I see the children doesn't have this property

Comment: more info about it you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286422/using-typescript-interface-with-a-recursive-json